Custom deserializer to deserialize a HashMap over arbitrary types
I have a tricky situation where I have a collection of key-value pairs, and I need a custom serde Deserializer (custom data format in serde documentation) that can map those pairs over a struct.
The key-value pairs look something like this:
("device:address:ip", "127.0.0.1"),
("device:address:port", "9001"),
("device:keys:0", "0000"),
("device:keys:1", "1111"),

And the idea is to be able to deserialize them over top of a data model such as this one:
struct DeviceAddress {
  ip: String,
  port: u16
}

struct DeviceConfig {
  address: DeviceAddress
  keys: Vec<String>
}

struct Config {
  device: DeviceConfig
}

In that scenario, the goal is to deserialize a HashMap<String, String> of such key-value pairs onto the Config struct. Instead of a &str input, I am looking at a **HashMap<String, String> ** as input to the deserializer.
To be as clear as possible, as serde walks the data model:

deserialize struct (Config)
deserialize struct field (device)
deserialize struct (DeviceConfig)
deserialize struct field (address)
deserialize struct (DeviceAddress)
deserialize struct field (ip)
deserialize value (String)

I need to construct this key:
device:address:ip
After which I can lookup the value in the HashMap of key-value pairs to resolve deserialization in step 7 (resolving value of the struct field).
Question
I know the approach I need to take to do this; however, where I am stuck is within the deserializer, how do I keep track of the path as the serde deserialization infrastructure walks over the data model?

why wouldn't you deserialize your entries into a HashMap<String, String> then you just parse the keys and produce the structures that you need. I think it would be fun to write. If you write a custom deserializer you would have to produce that anyway. I deleted my previous message because maybe it was not what you wanted, though the question is are you in control of the serialized key-value pairs? Would it possible to change the way they are serialized?

the plan is to use a HashMap<String, String> as the input to the deserializer. I have control over the serialized key-value pairs, and I could take the approach of writing a parser, and map the data by hand for every data model in the application, but I figured with a serde deserializer, I can eliminate parsing and also trivially map the pairs onto my data model. The set of pairs will grow over time as new functionality is introduced into the application, and more models will need to be mapped.

Why don't you serialize the data like this: {"device": {"address": {"ip": "127.0.0.1", "port": 9001}, "keys": ["0000", "1111"]}}?

There are existing data stores with an extensive amount of the key-value pairs. It's possible to transform the key-value pairs into JSON, and then deserialize them, but I want to avoid the cost. It's also too cost-prohibitive to transform the data stores (they aren't all under my control anyway).

I'll also point out that the data model in the question is not anything close to the complete data model. There are dozens of different data models now, and there will be more in the near future (and more key-value paths too, naturally).

This is more a job to a custom deserializer than to a custom Deserialize impl.

Yes, my question is how to implement a Deserializer (eg. "custom data format" from serde documentation) with a HashMap<String, String> as an input, and specifically my question is how to build up a string (as state) such as "device:address:ip" as serde walks the data model

I attempted this, but it bombs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=603a55d3786923bab42d5af287039d08. It's wip, but I am putting out there maybe it helps you. If you add 2 empty keys, it's going to work but it is not scalable. I am going to look tomorrow . The snippet takes advantage of the "pointer_mut": https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#method.pointer_mut

You need to add: keys: vec!["".to_string(), "".to_string()] to make it work. There is also another problem, the port number. In your input keys it is a string and in the structure it is an u16. Serde does not allow you to assign a string on top of a number and it doesn't attempt an automatic conversion.

I think the snippet needs a little bit more work to initialize the arrays because you could have objects inside the json arrays. I think it's going to work...

I found a pathway to solving this deserialization problem by thinking more about how serde walks the data structure. Serde provides information about structs and their fields that a deserializer can remember while being walked by the serde deserialization infrastructure.
For this particular deserialization implementation, the idea is to build up a key path as the deserializer walks over the data model, and then resolve a value from that key path when reaching a leaf, such as the value to be emitted for a struct field.
It looks like this:
struct ConfigMap<'a>(HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>);

struct Deserializer<'a> {
    config: &'a ConfigMap<'a>,
    fields: Vec<&'static str>,
    key: Vec<String>
}

impl <'a> Deserializer<'a> {
    pub fn new(config: &'a ConfigMap<'a>) -> Self {
        Deserializer {
            config,
            fields: vec![],
            key: vec![]
        }
    }
    pub fn read<T: FromStr>(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let key = self.key.join(":");
        self.key.pop();
        self.config.0
            .get(key.as_str())
            .and_then(|v| v.parse().ok())
    }
}

impl <'de, 'a> serde::de::Deserializer<'de> for &'a mut Deserializer<'de> {
    type Error = serde::de::value::Error;

    fn deserialize_any<V>(self, _: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        Err(serde::de::Error::custom(
            "Deserialization to target type is unsupported"))
    }

    fn deserialize_bool<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<bool>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_bool(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_i8<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<i8>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_i8(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_i16<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<i16>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_i16(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_i32<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<i32>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_i32(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_i64<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<i64>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_i64(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_u8<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<u8>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_u8(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_u16<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<u16>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_u16(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_u32<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<u32>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_u32(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_u64<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<u64>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_u64(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_f32<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<f32>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_f32(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_f64<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<f64>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_f64(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_char<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<char>().unwrap_or_default();
        visitor.visit_char(value)
    }

    fn deserialize_string<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        let value = self.read::<String>();
        visitor.visit_string(value.unwrap_or_default())
    }

    fn deserialize_map<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        visitor.visit_map(self)
    }

    fn deserialize_struct<V>(self, name: &'static str, fields: &'static [&'static str], visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        self.fields.clear();
        for field in fields.iter() {
            self.fields.push(field);
        }

        self.deserialize_map(visitor)
    }

    fn deserialize_identifier<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>
    {
        if let Some(field) = self.fields.pop() {
            self.key.push(field.to_string());
            let value = visitor.visit_str(field);
            return value;
        }

        Err(serde::de::Error::custom("invalid field"))
    }

    forward_to_deserialize_any! {
        enum ignored_any tuple tuple_struct seq
        newtype_struct unit_struct unit option
        byte_buf bytes str
    }
}

impl <'de, 'a> MapAccess<'de> for Deserializer<'de> {
    type Error = serde::de::value::Error;

    fn next_key_seed<K>(&mut self, seed: K) -> Result<Option<K::Value>, Self::Error>
    where
        K: DeserializeSeed<'de>
    {
        if self.fields.len() > 0 {
            seed.deserialize(&mut *self).map(Some)
        } else {
            self.key.pop();
            Ok(None)
        }
    }

    fn next_value_seed<V>(&mut self, seed: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: DeserializeSeed<'de>
    {
        seed.deserialize(&mut *self)
    }
}


This serializer is now capable of deserializing this example:
#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
pub struct Address {
    pub ip: String,
    pub port: u16
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
pub struct Device {
    pub address: Address,
    pub enabled: bool
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub device: Device
}

let mut config = HashMap::new();
config.insert("device:address:ip", "127.0.0.1");
config.insert("device:address:port", "9206");
config.insert("device:enabled", "true");

let map = ConfigMap(config);
let mut deserializer = Deserializer::new(&map);
let config: Config = Config::deserialize(&mut deserializer).expect("failed to parse");

println!("{:?}", config);

// Config { device: Device { address: Address { ip: "127.0.0.1", port: 9206 }, enabled: true } }



This is not a complete example. It may have bugs and isn't able to deserialize vectors or option fields, but the approach otherwise gets very close to the original question.

I followed my original idea and I came up with this code:
cargo.toml
[package]
name = "Deserialization"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "^1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "^1.0"

use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{self, de, Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde_json::{json, Value};

fn de_u16_or_string_as_u16<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u16, D::Error>
{
    match Value::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        Value::String(s) => s.parse().map_err(de::Error::custom),
        Value::Number(num) if num.as_u64().is_some() => {
            let n64 = num.as_u64().unwrap();
            if n64 > u64::from(u16::MAX) {
                let msg = format!("Integer value greater than {} which is the maximum value allowed", u16::MAX);
                Err(de::Error::custom(msg))
            } else {
                Ok(n64 as u16)
            }
        }
        x => Err(de::Error::custom(format!("The value cannot be assigned to an u16 property: {:?}", x))),
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
pub struct DeviceAddress {
    pub ip: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "de_u16_or_string_as_u16")]
    pub port: u16
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
struct DeviceConfig {
    pub address: DeviceAddress,
    pub keys: Vec<String>
}
#[derive(Debug, Default, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    device: DeviceConfig
}

fn deserialize(config_map: &HashMap<&str, &str>) -> Result<Config, String> {

    // The idea is to restore the objects hierarchy in root and then use the default serializer
    let mut root= json!({});

    fn assign_value (json_object: &mut Value, key_parts: &[&str], value: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
        // I want to see if the first key_part is a number
        let property = key_parts[0];

        let is_last = key_parts.len() == 1;
        let array_index= property.parse::<usize>();
        match json_object {
            Value::Array(values) => {
                match array_index {
                    Ok(index) => {
                        if values.len() <= index {
                            values.resize(index + 1, Value::Null)
                        }
                        if is_last {
                            values[index] = Value::String(value.to_string());
                            Ok(())
                        } else {
                            // At this point I want to make sure I am assigning something to index
                            // in case it is null. I am going on a limb here and assume I cannot have arrays of arrays
                            // Not sure if it makes sense to have them in a configuration.
                            if values[index].is_null() {
                                values[index] = json!({});
                            }
                            assign_value(&mut values[index], &key_parts[1..], value)

                        }
                    }
                    _ => Err(format!("Expected an array index. Got a string property instead: {}.", property))
                }
            }
            Value::Object(map) => {
                match array_index {
                    Ok(_) => {
                      // I am dealing with an array index and I have an object - it's an error
                        Err (format!("Expecting an array to assign a numeric index {}.", property))
                    }
                    _ => {
                        let property_as_string = property.to_string();
                        // I am dealing with an object
                        if is_last {
                            map.insert(property_as_string, Value::String(value.to_string()));
                            Ok(())
                        } else {
                            let property_value = map.get_mut(&property_as_string);
                            if property_value.is_some() {
                                assign_value(property_value.unwrap(), &key_parts[1..], value)
                            } else {
                                let next_property= key_parts[1];
                                let next_array_index = next_property.parse::<usize>();
                                if next_array_index.is_ok() {
                                    map.insert(property.to_string(), json!([]));
                                } else {
                                    map.insert(property.to_string(), json!({}));
                                }

                                let pv = map.get_mut(&property_as_string).unwrap();
                                assign_value(pv, &key_parts[1..], value)
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            _ =>
                Err("Programming error!".to_string())
        }

    }

    for (key, value) in config_map {
        let key_parts: Vec<&str> = key.split(":").collect();
        let result = assign_value(&mut root, &key_parts, value);
        // Return at the first error encountered - there is no point in continuing when something is off
        if let Err(msg) = result {
            return Err (msg)
        }
    }

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&root).unwrap());
    serde_json::from_value(root).map_err(|err|  err.to_string())

}


fn main() {
    let mut config = HashMap::new();
    config.insert("device:address:ip", "127.0.0.1");
    config.insert("device:address:port", "9206");
    config.insert("device:keys:0", "0000");
    config.insert("device:keys:1", "1111");
    config.insert("device:keys:2", "2222");
    println!("{:?}", deserialize(&config))

}


It prints:
{
  "device": {
    "address": {
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "9206"
    },
    "keys": [
      "0000",
      "1111",
      "2222"
    ]
  }
}
Ok(Config { device: DeviceConfig { address: DeviceAddress { ip: "127.0.0.1", port: 9206 }, keys: ["0000", "1111", "2222"] } })


A few points:

It handles errors and it stops at the first error encountered
The idea is that it builds the in-memory json object from the flattened list of configs and then it deserializes that object to the struct objects.
I added a custom deserializer to deserialize strings into u16. If you have other primitive values, you probably need to add a deserializer for each primitive type to convert from a string to that type.
I assume that the flattened configs define completely the data in the struct objects. For instance, if you have arrays, then the indexes in the configs are contiguous, starting to 0, and there are no gaps.
If you comment out the line with device:keys:1, you get this error: Err("invalid type: null, expected a string") and the json is:

  "device": {
    "address": {
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "9206"
    },
    "keys": [
      "0000",
      null,
      "2222"
    ]
  }
}



the algorithm can be used with other structures, in other words it is scalable to other struct hierarchies. However, I didn't test other structures 
I am not entirely happy with the array allocation. Maybe one option would be to set the capacity to 10 items or so, depending of what you expect in average. As is the algorithm keeps extending the array depending on the index it encounters. It would be more efficient to read the higher indexes first but given that they are strings you don't get the proper order anyway.
the assign_value function is recursive, however, I don't think it is a problem given the depth of your flattened hierarchy.
the algorithm doesn't accept mixing numeric indexes with string properties at the same level. It doesn't make sense, imo.
the error messages can be improved to provide more context information by passing the key to the assign_value function, and perhaps by keeping track of the prefix of the key that was already scanned to pinpoint the exact level where the error occurs. As an alternative, the assign_value function could take the key and an index parameter instead of the array slice that represents the remaining portion of the key that needs to be scanned.

Note: I noticed that in your answer to your own post you changed the definition of the structures. I went with the version that was in your question.

I appreciate the effort you put in. Thank you. I considered this approach when you proposed it, but I wasn't happy with the idea of transforming the data (memory allocations, cycles), and I wasn't convinced the complexity of this solution would be less than writing a dedicated deserializer. The nice thing about your solution is that because it uses serde_json it's very robust across a large range of data structures as long as you're able to transform the source model. For my needs I only need primitives, sequences (Vec), and maps (HashMap),

You're welcome. I think you have to choose the best solution given your requirements :-)
